# import sql file size in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to import an sql file to phpmyadmin.Its size is 375MB.I have changed upload_max_filesize,memory_limit and post_max_size in php.ini and restarted the wamp server but its not working.

Kindly help me how to do this!

Comment: thanks for the reply.I am on local host ie local server

Comment: kindly wriet the query.I am a newbie

Comment: can you specify all configuration values that you have changed?

Comment: Describe "it's not working" in more details. What do you see on-screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily through command prompt.

Run following command:

```
mysql -u <user_name> <Database_name>  < <sql_file_name>
```

Specify full path of your SQL file.